# How express in UML that there are multiple instances of given component type

Tags: uml

I work on system with such architecture:

- There are two types of components, let’s call them CLIENT and SERVER.
- There is only one instance of CLIENT component and there might be
  multiple instances of SERVER component.
- CLIENT uses HTTP interfaces of those SERVERs (they are the same interfaces).

What diagram should I use to represent those concepts and how it could look like?

I have tried with Component Diagram:

[image]

but this diagram does not say that there are multiple servers and single client.

Comment: Who is your audience?  Are you talking about how servers/services get deployed?  If so you might need a UML Deployment Diagram.  Are you talking about how the client and servers coordinate?  Then you might need an Activity Diagram or a Collaboration Diagram.  All that really matters is the audience two whom you are trying to communicate this aspect of your design.

Comment: I would like to express somehow that the CLIENT is able to perform its functionality on multiple SERVERs. In general CLIENT detects SERVERs and makes come configuration requests on them using HTTP. It is not important here what requested it sends or where those components are deployed. In typical case where there is only one server and multiple clients Component Diagram like this one I provided seems to be enough. I would like to highlight this is not a typical case.

Comment: the reason I ask is that UML diagrams are intended to convey a concept.  Many times it is less important to convey the cardinality of clients and servers, but more important to detail how they work together.  Do be careful you aren't trying to overload your diagrams.

Comment: I agree. But in this case it is important to understand cardinality, especially that this is not typical case. I am aware that I should not overload diagrams, so I do not want to show Deployment Diagram because it allows me to express cardinality, but requires to do something more what is not important.

Answer (score 4):

A [component diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html) shows the relation between components that have the following semantic:

> A Component is a **self-contained** unit that encapsulates the state and
>   behavior of a number of Classifiers. A Component specifies a **formal
>   contract** of the services that it provides to its clients and those
>   that it requires from other Components or services in the system in
>   terms of its provided and required **Interfaces**.

You can imagine the component as a kind of big class, that is self-contained, and can be substituted with components that implement the same interfaces.

In the component diagram, you can show that a component implements and/or requires several different interfaces,  you can show [dependencies](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html) between interfaces of inter-related components, but you can't show that there are several instances of the same component nor that there is multiple use of the same interface by different component instantiations.

If you want to show a particular configuration of component instantiation, you need to use a [deployment diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams-overview.html):

- you could show how the [artifacts](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/artifact.html) (executables, dlls, ...) corresponding to components are distributed
- you can show how the components corresponding to an artifact are instantiated on [deployment targets](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams.html#deployment-target) (e.g. devices, servers, or even OS precesses on the same server).
- you can show the [communication path](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams.html#communication-path) needed to connect the interfaces of components on different nodes

Comment: I do not want to overload diagram with things that are not relevant for what I would like to explain. How and where components are deployed does not matter. SERVER components may be deployed on the same device or different. I only want to emphasize that number of clients and number of servers are strictly enforced by architecture

Comment: Then put a comment to document your constraint on your component diagram